# Publishing on GitHub a Polymer component with multiple sub components

Tags: html, git, polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I have a created a web component, let's call it `a-1.html`, this is the main web component that I would like to publish, but this component also depends on another component that I created, `b-2.html`, and `b-2.html` also depends on a third component that I created `c-3.html`.

I have followed Polymer's [Create reusable elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html) guide in order to publish my element on GitHub, everything worked fine in terms of development (they were already developed), and I made the documentation, and I published on GitHub, but I'm facing 1 problem.

The guide deals as if you have a single component to be published, and it mentions that if there's any dependencies, I should place them, but what if my dependencies are still local dependencies? I can't put `b-2.html` and `c-3.html` in *bower.json*, because they are not yet online.

So later on, when I'm installing my element using `bower install <username>/element`, the element is not working because it's missing `b-2.html` and `c-3.html`, also the online demo (Github page using gp.sh) is not working.

For this situation, where should I place these files in order to have a complete working repo on GitHub, and also a working demo.

Directory:

```
bower_components
--- lots of compoenents
--- including b-2 and c-3 added manually by me
---- in order for the demo to work locally, but since they 
----- aren't in bower.json, this won't work eventually
bower.json
demo
---index.html
index.html
README.md
test
---basic-test.html
---index.html
a-1.html
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing multiple elements in a *GitHub* repository is exactly the same as publishing a single one. The *b-2.html* and *c-3.html* elements in your case should be placed besides *a-1.html* in the directory:

```
bower.json
a-1.html
b-2.html
c-3.html
```

Unless specified in an *ignore* section of the *bower.json* file, these should be installed by *bower*.

In my point of view, the [*main*](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#main) section of the *bower.json* file is here subtle. Multiple elements should be considered as individual which could be used independently. Here could be a *main* section for your situation:

```
"main": [
  "a-1.html",
  "b-2.html",
  "c-3.html"
]
```

However, if you wish to document your elements with an *iron-component-page* component, according to the [Polymer 1.0 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/documentation) all elements should be imported in a single *html* page. The recommended way of setting up the components would be a subdirectory for each component in order to write a demo page per component. I did that in a personal project including several elements to define an *UML* model: [polymeria-uml](https://github.com/bdulac/polymeria/).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted `:)`